# Setting id attribute to datatables 1.10.11 <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using datatables 1.10.11.

As per the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId), i can set the rowId using following syntax:

`$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    rowId: 'staffId'
} );`

I am not creating datatable using Ajax. 
I have two text boxes and "Add" button on left hand side and one datatable on right hand side. When i click on "Add", a new row is added to datatable. I hope that makes sense.

I need unique id attribute for each row for my use. I have tried doing so but no success at all.

According to documentation, this feature is available since DataTables 1.10.8

Did anyone solved this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You have tried ...? Assign a unique attribute from the JSON / AJAX source, that should be it. If you have a unique `_id` in all your rows, then `rowId: '_id'` ...

Comment: I am not creating datatable using Ajax.

I have two text boxes and "Add" button on left hand side and one datatable on right hand side.

When i click on "Add", a new row is added to datatable.
I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I am editing the question to add my scenario to the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

For add ID to tr element you con use `rowId` and especify the column that contain your id.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable(
{
  columns: [
     {data:"staffId"},//Remember specified the column
     {data:"position"},
     {data:"office"},
     {data:"age"},
     {data:"date"},
     {data:"salary"}
  ],
  rowId: 'staffId' //Reference to column data
});
```

For your button add, you should create the object and add to Table using `row.add` and `draw` for show in your table, for example:

```
$("#btnAdd").on("click",function(){

    var rowID = $("#rowId").val();//Get value of TextBox

    var new_object = { 
                       staffId: rowID, //New rowId
                       position: 'Developer', 
                       office: "Peru", 
                       age: 25, 
                       date: "2016/03/25", 
                       salary: "$ 58.200" 
                     };

  myTable.row.add(
      new_object
  ).draw();

});
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/65/